# How to create for loop for the below case in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the variables

```
P = [X, Y];
C = 0.5;
Q = -C+P(2);
```

Where, `X` takes the value of `(1,1)` and `Y` takes the value of `(2,1)` from the data (which is given below). I have to run a loop to calculate `Q` for all of the values from the data in the following way:

```
(1,2)(2,2), ..., (1,n)(2,n)
```

I tried using `cellfun` (where I used `num2cell` to change two rows into one single row with the cell values) but am not getting the required output.

```
data =[1 2 3 4 5 6;2 3 5 8 9 7];
[rows, columns] = size(data);
```

Comment: It seems `Q` only depends on `P(2)` which is equal to `Y`, which if I understand you right takes the values in the second row of `data`. In this case, wouldn't `Q` simply be `-C + data(2,:)`? I don't see a need for a loop here.

Comment: It would help if you gave the desired `Q` output for this input example.

Comment: I agree there's no need of loop for the case given above, am actually running a large data value(2*2286) and also that i have to assign the P[x,y] to some other variable( T=[xT(i); A.*xT(i)^2+B.*xT(i)+C];
      d=norm(P-T);) so i would be requiring a loop i beleive